# jQuery datepicker works but Spring controller gets null date

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I know this should be quite simple but I don't see where is the problem.
I have these two jquery datepickers:

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#iniDate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", firstDay: 1, changeYear: true });
                $( "#endDate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", firstDay: 1, changeYear: true });
            });
</script>
```

And the JSP:

```
<form:form method="post" action="result" commandName="mainForm">
      <p>Fecha inicio: <input type="text" id="iniDate" path="iniDate"/></p>
      <p>Fecha fin: <input type="text" id="endDate" path="endDate"/></p>
      <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Go"></p>
</form:form>
```

When I click on the text box and select a date, it is properly copied in the field, but when I submit the form I get always a "null" when reading its value in the controller that handles its POST method.

Any ideas?

Comment: how is the value read in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give name to those input fileds and if it not uses then remove path

```
<p>Fecha inicio: <input type="text" id="iniDate" name="iniDate"/></p>
<p>Fecha fin: <input type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate"/></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type="text" id="iniDate" name="iniDate"/>
```

The name atribute is required because when form submit then it automatically maps with pojo class fields in spring-mvc and pojo class variable name must be same with the attribute name.
As we know that in jsp we use

```
  <jsp:useBean id="person" type="" class="">
     <jsp:setProperty name="person" property="" value="" />  
 </jsp:useBean>
```

This did the same operation that is mapping fields with java bean class i.e. pojo class.